# How to print ArrayList in JSF Facelets

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, arraylist, facelets

I have been trying to print the values from an `ArrayList<String>` in JSF Facelets, but with no luck. The value is getting stored in an ArrayList but the output is blank on the page.

Bean file:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="newCompanyName")
@SessionScoped
public class CompanyNames implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String companyName;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        list.add(companyName);
        System.out.println("Size of array list is : "+list.size());

        for (String number : list) {
            System.out.println("Number = " + number);
        }       
    }

    public CompanyNames(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

public CompanyNames() {
}
}
```

Here is my JSF file from an XHTML 1.0 Transitional file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body> 
        <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{CompanyNames.list}"> 
            <h1>#{item}</h1> 
        </ui:repeat> 
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{CompanyNames.list}"> <h1>#{item}</h1> </ui:repeat>
```

use

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{newCompanyName.list}"> <h1>#{item}</h1> </ui:repeat>
```

You will also need a getList method for the class CompanyNames

```
public List<String> getList() {
    return this.list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much James. However I tried using newCompanyName.list before but I was missing a getList method. I was able to resolve the problem with your suggestion. Thanks :)

Comment: If your question has been answered please click the check icon to inform other users that your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `companyNames.list` instead of `CompanyNames.list` and you will also need the `get()` function of `list`.